# MS Access 2013 - Filter values in a list box, based on value in a Text box

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have made a form with a Listbox displaying a lot of names and addressees based on a query. How can I filter the names in the form, based on a Text box in the same form?

(Not all the names are relevant for every record)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter Access Combo Boxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822561/filter-access-combo-boxes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The listbox has a RowSource, so you can modify it on the fly:

```
Me!Listbox.RowSource = "SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE ..."
Me!Listbox.Requery
```

to modify the SQL with the value in the Textbox, use the Textbox AfterUpdate event

Comment: That simplified things a bit :)

Comment: That is such a great solution. I've been struggling with a way more complex one, and it took forever to run. This runs in 2 secs! So fantastic :-)